# gdb: "No symbol table is loaded"

Tags: c, gdb

I keep getting this error mesage when trying to add a breakpoint in gdb.

I've used these commands to compile:

```
gcc -g main.c utmpib2.c -o main.o
and:
cc -g main.c utmpib2.c -o main.o
and also:
g++ -g main.c utmpib2.c -o main.o
```

I also tried "-ggdb" instead of "-g" and I still get that error message.

I then execute gdb:

```
$gdb
```

In gdb:

```
(gdb)exec-file main.o
(gdb)break 59
No symbol table is loaded. Use the "file" command.
```

Comment: Oh I meant main.o.  I updated it.  I tried also using "-ggdb" and it is still giving me the same problem.

Comment: Show us exactly how are you invoking gcc and gdb. Copy-paste to avoid any erors.

Comment: I updated my commands. This is really weird.  It just started working.  I know previously I was accessing gdb using "gdb a.out" and I was getting an error message about a.out not existing or something.  Then I switched to the "exec-file".  Now I tried with a.out and it says "This GDB was configured as "i486-linux-gnu" " and breakpoints can be set.

Comment: oh duh I was specifying the wrong file a.out.  I followed along a gdb tutorial without thinking to change the filename to my own.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

First of all, what you have is a fully compiled program, not an object file, so drop the `.o` extension. Now, pay attention to what the error message says, it tells you *exactly* how to fix your problem: "No symbol table is loaded. ***Use the "file" command***."

```
(gdb) exec-file test
(gdb) b 2
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
(gdb) file test
Reading symbols from /home/user/test/test...done.
(gdb) b 2
Breakpoint 1 at 0x80483ea: file test.c, line 2.
(gdb)
```

Or just pass the program on the command line.

```
$ gdb test
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.4
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
[...]
Reading symbols from /home/user/test/test...done.
(gdb) b 2
Breakpoint 1 at 0x80483ea: file test.c, line 2.
(gdb)
```

Answer (score 164):

You have to add extra parameter -g, which generates source level debug information. It will look like:

```
gcc -g prog.c
```

After that you can use gdb in common way.

Answer (score 10):

I have the same problem and I followed this [Post](https://coderwall.com/p/wyb2ug), it solved my problem.

Follow the following 2 steps:

1. Make sure the optimization level is `-O0`
2. Add `-ggdb` flag when compiling your program

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Whenever `gcc` on the compilation machine and `gdb`  on the testing machine have **differing versions**, you may be facing **debuginfo format incompatibility**.

To fix that, try downgrading the debuginfo format:

```
gcc -gdwarf-3 ...
gcc -gdwarf-2 ...
gcc -gstabs ...
gcc -gstabs+ ...
gcc -gcoff ...
gcc -gxcoff ...
gcc -gxcoff+ ...
```

Or match `gdb` to the `gcc` you're using.

Answer (score 1):

I met this issue this morning because I used the same executable in DIFFERENT OSes: after compiling my program with `gcc -ggdb -Wall test.c -o test` in my Mac(10.15.2), I ran `gdb` with the executable in Ubuntu(16.04) in my VirtualBox.

Fix: recompile with the same command under Ubuntu, then you should be good.