# LiteIDE debug message No executable specified use target exec

Tags: debugging, go, gdb, liteide

Try to debug In LightIde, . However, when I start debug, the following console message appear

```
(gdb)
10000015^error,msg="No symbol table is loaded. Use the \"file\" command."
(gdb)
10000016^error,msg="No executable specified, use `target exec'."
(gdb)
```

And it does not start debug.
What is missing?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your config: liteide - open project xxx.go , edit toolbar build config -> `BUILDARGS` ([like the `-g` flag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12794195/6309)).

For instance, you can try (as in this issue) `-gcflags "-N -l"`. As mentioned in [this thread](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/liteide-dev/sNoeuPGKq0A),

> if `BUILDARGS` setup includes: `-ldflags "-s"`, no debug info is loaded.