# GDB - How to handle "No Symbol Table"

Tags: c, gdb, symbols, debug-symbols, symbol-table

I have an application I would like to inspect and I don't have the sources to rebuild it and create the Symbol Table like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245685/gdb-no-symbol-table-is-loaded) (`gcc -g my_app.c`).

When I call the `info locals` I get the following error "**No symbol table info available**"

When I'm working with Eclipse even when I don't have the sources of the library it can resolve the arguments of the current function into *arg0, arg1... argN* and if I remember correctly also the members of objects.

Is there any way to generate a custom/generic/default symbol table, one that would satisfy GDB and would allow me to see the values of local variables and arguments?

Comment: No source, debug build or symbol table?  You're more stuffed than a Christmas turkey.

Comment: @MartinJames Do you have a more constructive comment?

Comment: Sadly, no.  My only option was a non-constructive comment.  If you have no symbol table and no debug build, you have nothing.

Comment: @MartinJames So how it is done in Eclipse?

Comment: @MP_: Google search [indicates](https://www.google.pl/search?q=eclipse+arg0+arg1&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=Q8ClVOvBGsS0UdKChPAK#q=eclipse+arg0+arg1), that you are confusing Eclipse with Java language. Can you confirm this sort of generic parameters' names does work in CDT?

Comment: BTW, this is why I prefer free software: when I need it, I can always get the source code and study it. It actually is less painful to avoid proprietary software. So if you don't have the source code, don't use your application (and try to replace it with some free software)

Comment: Thank you guys for the comments... I was confusing with Java!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the answer is No.

The local symbols are only useful for debugging so there is no alternative. If they have been discarded they are gone.

Comment: why arent the args visible at runtime? in other words, if I read "no symbol table info available", how can I see the arguments passed to the current function?

Comment: a function just gets the stack... the args are in there somewhere, you can probably inspect the stack, but figuring out what each byte means could be tricky.