# android native in eclipse - GDB

Tags: eclipse, debugging, gdb, adt

I am trying to debug a native android application in Eclipse. If it important, app is made with SFML library. To test I use my tablet (android  4.4), not avd.

After running debug, console throw things like this :

```
warning: Could not load shared library symbols for 137 libraries, e.g. /system/bin/linker.
Use the "info sharedlibrary" command to see the complete listing.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
warning: Unable to find dynamic linker breakpoint function.
GDB will be unable to debug shared library initializers
and track explicitly loaded dynamic code.
Could not AssignProcessToObject
```

and in debug perspective it is shown that debug process is terminated with status -1.

My configuration
[presenting something like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SfId.png)

On virtual device console say things like a 
`"No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command."`
or another message about memory with strange address like `0x2 / 0x1000000.`

What am I doing wrong trying to debug this application?

Comment: 1) Did you compile with `-g` option to leave debug symbols? See that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12794195
2) Didn't you strip the symbols with `gdb -s` or `strip`?
3) Is your shared lib path correct? See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14483445
4) could you try to create `.gdbinit` under your app build dir, and write to it `set sysroot ....` where `....` is a path to your `libs` folder with shared libraries?