# No Symbol Table using GDB on Compiled Programs

Tags: c, list, gdb, break

Let me preface this by stating this is for a project for my first C programming class.  I'm not going to give my code since it is working, but just need assistance with an error I receive from GDB during execution.

With that said, the first portion of my project was to write a program that will take any file in byte form, and locate strings of a certain length.  This works.  The next portion is I'm provided (3) compiled C files and I need to use GDB along with a hex editor and my program to figure out the hidden password to unlock the program.  I got the first one, but the second and third are increasing in difficulty and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my issue:

When I use GDB to start running the compiled file, I'm immediately met with a blinking cursor in GDB.  I press `cntrl c` to interrupt the program which pauses the program in its tracks.  I then enter `back` and get a list of (9) lines, their memory locations, and the names of their methods.  Here is  where my problem lies, if I want to go to `main()`, and I try to enter a break, it tells me `No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command`.

```
Starting program: [program path on university server] 
^C
Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0x00110430 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.12-
1.132.el6_5.3.i686
(gdb) list
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
(gdb) back
#0  0x00110430 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0x00c8f8d3 in __read_nocancel () from /lib/libc.so.6
#2  0x00c2972b in _IO_new_file_underflow () from /lib/libc.so.6
#3  0x00c2b44b in _IO_default_uflow_internal () from /lib/libc.so.6
#4  0x00c2ca5a in __uflow () from /lib/libc.so.6
#5  0x00c1f36c in _IO_getline_info_internal () from /lib/libc.so.6
#6  0x00c1f2b1 in _IO_getline_internal () from /lib/libc.so.6
#7  0x00c1e1ea in fgets () from /lib/libc.so.6
#8  0x0804851c in main ()
(gdb)
```

I've looked at other threads like [gdb: "No symbol table is loaded"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245685/gdb-no-symbol-table-is-loaded) and I don't think that this pertains to me since the files I'm attempting to "crack" are already compiled and provided to me.  So I'm not exactly debugging a C source file, but the compressed file after.

This is my struggle right now, and would appreciate any explanation or help with how I can solve the `No symbol table is loaded.` issue I'm having.

Comment: did you use -g flag to compile the program?

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245685/gdb-no-symbol-table-is-loaded?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: But you are not trying to enter breakpoint. You are trying to `list` source code in frame `#0`.

Comment: @user2979872 I can't compile it.  It's already a compiled C file provided by my professor that I have to try and enter with GDB.

Comment: @ks1322 I also tried `break 8` still the same response.  Sorry I did not put that `break` line in there.  But `list` and other commands I've tried result with the same response

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `No symbol table loaded` message you are getting is misleading: *all* GDB is telling you is that your binary does not have any debugging info in it.

Usually this is solved by rebuilding the binary with `-g` flag, but since you are given an already compiled and linked file, you can't do that.

Without debug info, certain commands, such as `list`, `break file.c:line`, or `break line` will *not* work. But other commands, such as: `disassemble` and `break function` *will* work, and that's the commands you'll have to use for this assignment.

> Is there a command list of codes that are available and not available

Not that I am aware of. But you can *deduce* what that list is from understanding what debugging info contains.

Debugging info generally contains:

1. Mapping from code address (i.e. program counter) to source file and line number. (Without such mapping, `list` and `break foo.c:123` can't work.)
2. Types and names of local and global variables. (Without this, `ptype` and `whatis` and `info locals` can't work.)
3. Location of local variables and parameters on the stack. (Again `info locals`, `print a_local_var`, `print &a_local_var` can't work.)

Comment: I LOVE YOU!  This is the answer.  Is there a command list of codes that are available and not available in these instances?  I'm new to GDB (only did one lab with it).

Comment: This is the answer.  Thank you @Employed Russian very much.  You saved some hair on my head.